# KnockoutJS default value not set when getJSON

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, getjson

I change from AngularJS to KnockoutJS. With the least piece I have a problem I spent now two days for already.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="account">Konto:</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: accounts, value: account</select>
</div>
```

This is account:

```
self.account = ko.observable('Bargeldkonto');
```

This works great when I define this I realized later. Second option is selected in my case:

```
self.accountstest = ko.observable([]);    
self.accountstest = ko.observable(['Avadis','Bargeldkonto','Bitcoin','Lohnkonto','Mietkaution','Sparen 3','Sparen 3 Kto. 2','Sparkonto Liam Noa','Sparkonto SQ','Trading SQ']);
```

But this way, it doesn't work. Always first is selected:

```
        self.accounts = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.getJSON("entry_account_mysql.php", function(data) {
            self.accounts(data);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log("accounts: " + self.accounts());
        });
```

I know it has to do with timing, but don't know have to behave with it in KnockoutJS.
Some say $getJson is not good. Funny, $.ajax works, but I receive now this error in console: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience.":

```
        self.accounts = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "entry_account_mysql.php",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                self.accounts(data);
            }
        });
```

Back to $.getJSON? But how?

Comment: You are missing the closing quotation character and closing bracket in your `<select data-bind="options: accounts, value: account>`.

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. But it's a copy paste error. I have a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your select in a virtual element binding `if`:

```
<!-- ko if: accounts.length -->
  <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: accounts, value: account"></select>
<--! /ko -->
```

This makes sure the element gets rendered only if `accounts` holds any elements, and by this, should solve your timing issues.